# How to use the Mongo aggregation method to join on one collection filed name to another collection filed value?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm on Spring boot 2 and Spring Data MongoDB.

At the front side, In user form, all the fields are displayed dynamically from the DB.

I have the "Filed" collection for all the fields.

So my Field collection looks like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f05a51dc9e77c00014bb3b5"),
    "fieldName" : "name",
    "fieldType" : "text"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f05a51dc9e77c00014b4523"),
    "fieldName" : "address",
    "fieldType" : "text"
}
```

User Collection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f058db405c9fc60965ce243"),
    "name" : "john",
    "address" : "US"
}
```

Now I want to join these two collections based on fileName filed of the Field collection and user collection.

I expect result:

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5f058db405c9fc60965ce243"),
   "fileds":[
   {
       "_id" : ObjectId("5f05a51dc9e77c00014bb3b5"),
       "fieldName" : "name",
       "fieldType" : "text",
       "value":"John"
   },
   {
       "_id" : ObjectId("5f05a51dc9e77c00014b4523"),
       "fieldName" : "address",
       "fieldType" : "text",
       "value":"US"
   }]
}
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick example how to achieve this using [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) and then doing a `$lookup` on the fields name.

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      userFields: {
        $objectToArray: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$userFields"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "fields",
      let: {
        field: "$userFields.k"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$$field",
                "$fieldName"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $addFields: {
            value: "$$field"
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "fields"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$fields"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      fields: {
        $push: "$fields"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JMw-sRxSZiD)